# Pynotify not working Jython

Tags: python, oracle, jython, pynotify

I am trying to build a Python application that connects to Oracle database and show notifications. Now loops and everything is working ok but accessing the Oracle database seems to be impossible.

I researched and found out that there are two ways to connect to Oracle via Python. If we are using native python we have to use the Oracle instant client. I want to ignore this path and use the next one. The other way is to use jython and access Oracle using the Oracle JDBC driver.

I managed to import the Oracle JDBC to jython

```
import sys
sys.path.append('ojdbc6.jar')
from oracle.jdbc.driver import OracleDriver
from java.sql import DriverManager
```

Now the problem arises when I try to import Pynotify.

```
import sys, pynotify
```

Error

```
[pos@IT-05 ~]$ ./r.py
Traceback (innermost last):
  File "./r.py", line 3, in ?
ImportError: no module named pynotify
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no pynotify for Jython. You'll need to use [java-gnome](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/)'s [`org.gnome.notify`](http://java-gnome.sourceforge.net/doc/api/4.1/org/gnome/notify/package-summary.html).